Unauthorized (401) while i sent a Post request to the server
when i try to add a post to my server i get 401 Unauthorized i sent my jwt in postman with Bearer jwt but nothing change . i think the probleme in the api where exactly i don't have any idea
i use django as backend and react as frontend those are all my code
urls.py :
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),

    path('', include('crm.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]

views.py :
from django.shortcuts import render ,redirect ,get_object_or_404          
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet, GenericViewSet
from .forms import CreateUserForm, LoginForm
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

#, UploadForm
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, action

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from .models import Post, PostImage

# - Authentication models and functions 
from django.contrib.auth.models import auth 
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def homepage(request):

    return render(request, 'crm/index.html')

def register(request):

    form = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method == "POST":

        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            return redirect("my-login")

    context = {'registerform':form}

    return render(request, 'crm/register.html', context=context)



def my_login(request):

    form = LoginForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():

            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username,password=password)

            if user is not None :

                auth.login(request, user)

                return redirect("dashboard")

    
    context = {'loginform':form}

    return render(request, 'crm/my-login.html', context=context)

def user_logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    
    return redirect("")

#def upload(request):
#   if request.POST:
#      form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
#     print(request.FILES)
    #    if form.is_valid():
#       form.save_()
#  return redirect(homepage)
    #return render(request, 'crm/upload.html', {'form' : UploadForm })

def post_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'posts':posts})

def detail_view(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    photos = PostImage.objects.filter(post=post)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {
        'post':post,
        'photos':photos
    })

@api_view(['POST'])
class PostsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)






@login_required(login_url="my-login")
def dashboard(request):

    return render(request, 'crm/dashboard.html')

serializers.py :
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post, PostImage



User = get_user_model()

class CustomUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    age = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    role = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=User.Role.choices, required=True)

    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password', 'age', 'role')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
    

class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ('id', 'post', 'image')

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = PostImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    uploaded_images = serializers.ListField(
        child = serializers.ImageField(max_length = 1000000, allow_empty_file = False, use_url = False),
        write_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'text', 'category', 'author', 'created_at', 'images', "uploaded_images")
    

    def create(self, validated_data):
        uploaded_images = validated_data.pop("uploaded_images")
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for image in uploaded_images:
            newpost_image = PostImage.objects.create(post=post, image=image)
    
        return post 

models.py :
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin , AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email field must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, name, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=150, default='Anonymous', unique=False)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('age'), blank=True, null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(18), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False)

    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        ADMIN = "ADMIN", "Admin"
        CLIENT = "CLIENT", "Client"
        ANALYST = "ANALYST", "Analyst"

    role = models.CharField(_('role'), max_length=50, choices=Role.choices, default=Role.CLIENT)
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'age', 'role']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            if not self.email:
                raise ValidationError("Email address is required.")
            elif User.objects.filter(email=self.email).exists():
                raise ValidationError("Email address must be unique.")
            elif not self.role:
                self.role = self.Role.CLIENT
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
class ClientManager(CustomUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(role=User.Role.CLIENT)

class Client(User):
    base_role = User.Role.CLIENT
    objects = ClientManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def welcome(self):
        return "Only for Client"

class AnalystManager(CustomUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(role=User.Role.ANALYST)

class Analyst(User):
    base_role = User.Role.ANALYST
    objects = AnalystManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def welcome(self):
        return "Only for Analysts"




class Post(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ('math', 'Math'),
        ('philosophy', 'Philosophy'),
        ('science', 'Science'),
        ('political', 'Political'),
        ('other', 'Other'),
    ]
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)  # Required field
    text = models.TextField(blank=False)  # Required field
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, blank=False)  # Required field
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # You can adjust the max length as needed
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # Automatically set to the current date and time when created
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "images")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='djangoposts/files/images', default="", null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title


i try to  put a jwt token in the Bearer Token in postman but nothing have change the same error still show up

my_login() uses django.contrib.auth.authenticate hence you are using Django’s Session authentication not JWT so you should rely on Cookies not Tokens. See this answer I gave recently for more details on how to use Session authentication.
